# Getting a decimal value from sensor using SMBus with Python

Tags: python, decimal, raspberry-pi, return-value, i2c

I have the TCN75A temperature sensor connected to my Raspberry Pi via SMBus and I get values from the sensor with a Python script just fine. However the values are all integers, but I want to get decimal values with two floaters. How can I do this?

The Python script I have looks like this:

```
import smbus
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT) #These two are LED lights, green and red
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x48 #This is the address found with i2cdetect in the RasPi command line.

def read():
  read = bus.read_byte_data(address, 0x00) #This returns integer values.
  return read

while True:
  output = read()
  if output < 25:
    GPIO.output(12, True)
    GPIO.output(18, False)
  else:
    GPIO.output(18, True)
    GPIO.output(12, False)
  print(output)
```

Comment: What sort of values do you expect to get? There's no built-in function to return floats from SMBus, you will have to manually convert the integers. But to do that you need to know what to expect.

Comment: Have you read http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21935D.pdf ?